# Where does member variable get created when object is created on heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am having a little confusion about memory allocation. Where does member variable get created (on stack or heap?) when object is created on heap? For example, say we have class Cat as follows.

```
class Cat { public: int itsage;};
```

Now suppose we have following line of code in main function.

```
Cat * Frisky= new Cat;
```

Now I guess here pointer variable Frisky is created on **stack** which stores memory address of memory on **heap**(Am I right?). But I am confused   where is integer variable itsage is created? Also what will happen if itsage was itself pointer? i.e.
`int * itsage;`

Thanks.

Comment: Someone needs to come along and post the good book link.

Comment: This should be covered in any introductory text. Here are some good [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itsage` is a subobject of `Cat` which means it is part of the the `Cat` object itself.  Therefore, it exists as part of the heap-allocated `Cat` object.  `new Cat` creates the `Cat` object and any subobjects, all within the same allocation.

If it were a pointer, this would still be true.  The pointer value would be part of the `Cat` object, but it could point to an `int` somewhere else.

Note that the C++ standard doesn't use the terms "stack" and "heap."  Function local variables (non-static) have *automatic storage duration* and objects created with `new T` have *dynamic storage duration.*  Under the hood, values with these storage durations are typically implemented using the stack and heap respectively, but a conforming implementation is not required to use stack or heap structures.